# D3 multi line chart

Tags: d3.js, linegraph

This is the data I have to draw on a D3 line graph, where the lines are **Addon**, **Loss**, **New**, **Repeat**. Same should be shown in the legend:

```
dataf: [
        {
          drugs: "BENEPALI",
          Addon: 328,
          Loss: 560,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "CIMZIA",
          Addon: 328,
          Loss: 460,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "COSENTYX",
          Addon: 265,
          Loss: 360,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 421,
        },
        {
          drugs: "ENBREL",
          Addon: 281,
          Loss: 260,
          New: 150,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "TALTZ",
          Addon: 290,
          Loss: 560,
          New: 150,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
      ],
```

I have some success with drawing the legend and plotting axis but not with  line. I think there is a problem with the data.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button @click="esCall(dataf, stacklist, 1460, 350)">es call</b-button>
    <div id="kmCurveLegend" style="margin-left: -150px; margin-top: 30px"></div>
    <div id="kmCurve" style="margin-top: 10px"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dataf: [
        {
          drugs: "BENEPALI",
          Addon: 328,
          Loss: 560,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "CIMZIA",
          Addon: 328,
          Loss: 460,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "COSENTYX",
          Addon: 265,
          Loss: 360,
          New: 250,
          Repeat: 421,
        },
        {
          drugs: "ENBREL",
          Addon: 281,
          Loss: 260,
          New: 150,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
        {
          drugs: "TALTZ",
          Addon: 290,
          Loss: 560,
          New: 150,
          Repeat: 321,
        },
      ],
      stacklist: ["Addon", "Loss", "New", "Repeat"],
      xlabel: [],
      sumstat: null,
      mktSegName: "",
      current_stacks: null,
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      svg: null,
      res: null,
      x1: null,
      minWidth: null,
      minHeight: null,
      stacks: null,
      totalStacks: null,
      data: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.kmLayout();
  },
  methods: {
    esCall(dataf, stacklist, w, h) {
      this.stacks = stacklist;
      this.data = dataf;
      this.minWidth = w;
      this.minHeight = h;
      this.kmLayout(this.minWidth, this.minHeight, this.data, this.stacks);
    },
    kmLayout(w, h, data, stacklist) {
      d3.selectAll("#KMGraph").remove();
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
      this.width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
      this.height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // append the svg object to the body of the page
      this.svg = d3
        .select("#kmCurve")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", "KMGraph")
        .attr("width", this.width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     
      //Grouping according to multiple MS

      var updatedData = [];
      for (var i in data) {
        updatedData.push(data[i]);
      }
      this.sumstat = d3.group(
        updatedData,
        (d) => d.Addon && d.Loss && d.New && d.Repeat
      );
      console.log("this.sumstat", this.sumstat);
  

      var x = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(
          data.map(function (d) {
            return d.drugs;
          })
        )
        .range([0, this.width]); // This controls the Horizontal position of the Axis

      // Draw the axis
      this.svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")") // This controls the vertical position of the Axis
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add Y axis
      var y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([
          0,
          d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return +d.Loss + d.Addon + d.New + d.Repeat;
          }),
        ])
        .range([this.height, 0]);
      this.svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      //tooltip
      this.tip = d3Tip()
        .attr("class", "d3-tip")
        .direction("e")
        .html(function (d, i) {
          return (
            "<div style='margin-top:20%;background-color:whitesmoke;border-radius:4px;color:black;padding:5px'><strong>" +
            i[0]
            // +
            // "</strong><br><strong>(  " +
            // i[1][parseInt(r / 10)] +
            // "," +
            // i[1][parseInt(r / 10)].sum +
            // ")</strong></div>"
          );
        });

      this.svg.call(this.tip);
      var dataArray = Array.from(this.sumstat, ([key, value]) => ({
        key,
        value,
      }));

      var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(
          stacklist.map(function (d) {
            return d;
          })
        )
        .range([
          "#e20000",
          "#377eb8",
          "#4daf4a",
          "#250056 ",
          "#ff9300",
          "#df216d",
          "#a65628",
          "#0768fd",
          "#00c221",
          "#9e54b0",
          "#ffff33",
          "#10558a",
          "#595959",
        ]);
      this.svg
        .selectAll(".line")
        .data(this.sumstat)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "lineKM")
        .attr("id", (d) => "kmCurve" + d[1])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
          console.log(d);
          console.log("color", d[0], color(d[0]));
          return color(d[0]);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.5)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
          return d3
            .line()
            .x((d) => {
              console.log("5555555555555555555555", x(d.drugs));
              return x(d.drugs);
            })
            .y((d) => {
              console.log("66666666666666666666666", y(d.Addon));
              return y(d.Addon);
            })(
            d[1].sort(function (a, b) {
              console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", b.Addon - a.Addon);
              return b.Addon - a.Addon;
            })
          );
    
        })
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.selectAll("#kmCurve" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
            "opacity",
            0.1
          );
          d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .call(this.tip)
        .on("mouseover", this.tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", this.tip.hide);
        this.svg
        .selectAll(".line")
        .data(this.sumstat)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "lineKM")
        .attr("id", (d) => "kmCurve" + d[1])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
          console.log(d);
          console.log("color", d[0], color(d[0]));
          return color(d[0]);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.5)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
          return d3
            .line()
            .x((d) => {
              console.log("5555555555555555555555", x(d.drugs));
              return x(d.drugs);
            })
            .y((d) => {
              console.log("66666666666666666666666", y(d.Loss));
              return y(d.Loss);
            })(
            d[1].sort(function (a, b) {
              console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", b.Loss - a.Loss);
              return b.Loss - a.Loss;
            })
          );
          

        })
        
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.selectAll("#kmCurve" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
            "opacity",
            0.1
          );
          d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .call(this.tip)
        .on("mouseover", this.tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", this.tip.hide);

this.svg
        .selectAll(".line")
        .data(this.sumstat)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "lineKM")
        .attr("id", (d) => "kmCurve" + d[1])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
          console.log(d);
          console.log("color", d[0], color(d[0]));
          return color(d[0]);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.5)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
          return d3
            .line()
            .x((d) => {
              console.log("5555555555555555555555", x(d.drugs));
              return x(d.drugs);
            })
            .y((d) => {
              console.log("66666666666666666666666", y(d.New));
              return y(d.New);
            })(
            d[1].sort(function (a, b) {
              console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", b.New - a.New);
              return b.New - a.New;
            })
          );
         
        })
        
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.selectAll("#kmCurve" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
            "opacity",
            0.1
          );
          d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .call(this.tip)
        .on("mouseover", this.tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", this.tip.hide);

this.svg
        .selectAll(".line")
        .data(this.sumstat)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "lineKM")
        .attr("id", (d) => "kmCurve" + d[1])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
          console.log(d);
          console.log("color", d[0], color(d[0]));
          return color(d[0]);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 3.5)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
          return d3
            .line()
            .x((d) => {
              console.log("5555555555555555555555", x(d.drugs));
              return x(d.drugs);
            })
            .y((d) => {
              console.log("66666666666666666666666", y(d.Repeat));
              return y(d.Repeat);
            })(
            d[1].sort(function (a, b) {
              console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", b.Repeat - a.Repeat);
              return b.Repeat - a.Repeat;
            })
          );
       
        })
        
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.selectAll("#kmCurve" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
            "opacity",
            0.1
          );
          d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .call(this.tip)
        .on("mouseover", this.tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", this.tip.hide);

       this.createLegend(stacklist);
    },
    createLegend(stacklist) {
      d3.selectAll("#KmLegends").remove();
  
      var stacks = stacklist;
      this.current_stacks = stacks;
      console.log("stacks", stacks);
      this.stackedZ = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .range([
          "#e20000",
          "#377eb8",
          "#4daf4a",
          "#250056 ",
          "#ff9300",
          "#df216d",
          "#a65628",
          "#0768fd",
          "#00c221",
          "#9e54b0",
          "#ffff33",
          "#10558a",
          "#595959",
        ])
        .domain(stacks);
      this.legendsvg = d3
        .select("#kmCurveLegend")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "legendKmCurve")
        .attr("id", "KmLegends")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 50);
      this.legendg = this.legendsvg.append("g");
      stacks.forEach((d, i) => {
        var position = i;
        this.legendg
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "legendCircle")
          .attr("id", "legendCircle" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_"))
          .attr("r", 10)
          .attr("cy", 20)
          .attr("cx", position * 165 + 225)
          .attr("fill", this.stackedZ(d))
          .on("click", () => {
            this.addOrDelete(d);
          })
          .on("mouseover", () => {
            console.log("circle d", d);
            d3.selectAll(".lineKM").style("opacity", 0.2);
            d3.select("#kmCurve" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
              "opacity",
              2
            );
            d3.selectAll(".legendCircle").style("opacity", 0.1);
            d3.select("#legendCircle" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_")).style(
              "opacity",
              2
            );
          })
          .on("mouseout", () => {
            d3.selectAll(".lineKM").style("opacity", 1);
            d3.selectAll(".legendCircle").style("opacity", 1);
          })
          .append("svg:title")
          .text(d);

        this.legendg
          .append("text")
          .attr("class", "legendKM" + d.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_"))
          .on("click", (d, i, key) => {
            console.log("key of text", key);
            if (
              document.getElementById(
                "kmCurve" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              ).style.opacity == 1
            ) {
              d3.selectAll(
                "#kmCurve" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              ).style("opacity", 0);
              d3.selectAll(
                "." + "legendKM" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              )
                .style("text-decoration", "line-through")
                .style("opacity", 0.2);
              d3.selectAll(
                "#legendCircle" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              )
                .style("text-decoration", "line-through")
                .style("opacity", 0.2);
              this.$forceUpdate();
            } else {
              d3.selectAll(
                "#kmCurve" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              ).style("opacity", 1);
              d3.selectAll(
                "." + "legendKM" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              )
                .style("text-decoration", "none")
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .style("white-space", "nowrap")
                .style("text-overflow", "ellipsis");
              d3.selectAll(
                "#legendCircle" + d[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").innerHTML
              )
                .style("text-decoration", "line-through")
                .style("opacity", 1);
              this.$forceUpdate();
            }
            this.$forceUpdate();

            this.addOrDelete(d[0].innerHTML);
          })
          .text(d)
          .attr("y", 20)
          .attr("x", position * 165 + 240)
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
          .style("font-size", "18px")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0,6)")
          .append("svg:title");
        this.$forceUpdate();
      });
    },
    addOrDelete(name) {
      this.current_stacks.includes(name)
        ? this.filterData(name)
        : this.addData(name);
    },
    filterData(name) {
      console.log("this.current_stacks.length", this.current_stacks.length);
      if (this.current_stacks.length == 1) {
        return;
      }
      this.current_stacks = this.current_stacks.filter((obj) => {
        return obj != name;
      });
      this.kmUpdatedLayout(
        this.minWidth,
        this.minHeight,
        this.data,
        this.current_stacks
      );
      this.legendUpdate(name, 0);
    },
    addData(name) {
      if (this.current_stacks.includes(name)) {
        return;
      }
      this.current_stacks.push(name);
      this.kmUpdatedLayout(
        this.minWidth,
        this.minHeight,
        this.data,
        this.current_stacks
      );
      this.legendUpdate(name, 1);
    },
    legendUpdate(name, status) {
      status
        ? d3
            .selectAll("." + "legendKM" + name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_"))
            .style("text-decoration", "none")
            .style("opacity", 1)
        : d3
            .selectAll("." + "legendKM" + name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_"))
            .style("text-decoration", "line-through")
            .style("opacity", 0.4);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet / fiddle / sandbox ?

Comment: no i dont have anything as such but what i have is the only above code which i have posted

Comment: i was able to figure it out @MichaelRovinsky 
thank you click here if you still want to have a look
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-leaf-dkl99?file=/src/App.vue)